# Reusing inline data in gnuplot

Tags: c, pipe, gnuplot, inline

Does anyone know how I can reuse inline data in Gnuplot, I've been googling it and can't find nothing everything suggests to input the data gain? Basically reuse the '-' file.

Answer (score 0):

in place of a bare `replot`, you can use `refresh` if you're using gnuplot 4.3 or newer.  If you actually want to add more data to be plotted, I think you're out of luck.

e.g.

```
plot '-' u 1:2
 1 2
 2 3
 e
set label "Hello World!" at 1.5,2.5
refresh
```

Answer (score 0):

*since I stumbled over this old question via Google...*

There are two ways to having "inline data" (data in the gnuplot file):

1. the special filename `'-'`, which reads the lines immediately following the plot command. This data can only be used once.
2. named datablocks with here documents, which can be reused:

```
$Data << EOD
0 0 0
1 1 1
2 2 4
3 3 9
4 4 16
EOD

plot $Data using 1:2 title 'linear' with linespoints, \
     $Data using 1:3 title 'quadratic' with linespoints
```

See http://gnuplot.info/docs_5.5/loc3521.html

Comment: Yes, since gnuplot 5.0 (Jan 2015) you can use datablocks. If you want to use the identical `'-'` data twice you have to provide the data twice. There is an answer about this somewhere here on SO. If I find the link I will add it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `blockdata` is most useful see [Gnuplot: Histogram plots with inline data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25059212)

However:
Reading `gnuplot` embedded help:

```
gnuplot> help plot  datafile  special-filenames
```

states:

> ... The special filename `'-'` specifies that the data are inline;
> ... If you use `'-'` ... you may need to enter the data more than once.
> ... A blank filename ('') specifies that the previous filename should be reused.
> ... (If you use both `'-'` and `''` on the same `plot` command, you'll need to have two sets of inline data, as in the example above.)

so you can do:

```
gnuplot> plot '-' using 1:2, '' using 1:3
input data ('e' ends) >
```

and then paste the same data twice:

```
      0.000              0              0    
      0.001            104             51
      0.002            202            101
      0.003            298            148
      0.0031           290            149
      0.004            289            201
      0.0041           291            209
      0.005            310            250
      0.010            311            260
      0.020            280            240
e
input data ('e' ends) > input data ('e' ends) > input data ('e' ends) > input data ('e' ends) > input data ('e' ends) > input data ('e' ends) > input data ('e' ends) > input data ('e' ends) > input data ('e' ends) > input data ('e' ends) > input data ('e' ends) >
      0.000              0              0    
      0.001            104             51
      0.002            202            101
      0.003            298            148
      0.0031           290            149
      0.004            289            201
      0.0041           291            209
      0.005            310            250
      0.010            311            260
      0.020            280            240
e
input data ('e' ends) > input data ('e' ends) > input data ('e' ends) > input data ('e' ends) > input data ('e' ends) > input data ('e' ends) > input data ('e' ends) > input data ('e' ends) > input data ('e' ends) > input data ('e' ends) >
gnuplot>
```

[output graphic plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLhut.png)

---

---

environment under test:

```
linuxuser@ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 4.15.0-74-generic #84-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 19 08:06:00 UTC 2019 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

linuxuser@ubuntu:~$ gnuplot -V
gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 2
```